# Div not getting into correct position

Tags: html, css

I'm getting some problems with a div, this not is getting into correct position, look:
http://prntscr.com/2wwajd

**HTML**:
http://pastebin.com/JecDqRJy

**CSS**:
http://pastebin.com/Svszs3xU

Comment: please paste your code instead of the links

Comment: it's so big, i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not so weird. Your menu on the left has no wrapper and no width. Besides, it does not *float*.

I have added a wrapper for the menu links, here: **http://jsfiddle.net/TT2Qa/**

`HTML`:

```
 <div class="menu">
    <a href="home.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/home.gif" id="home" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Home</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="anjos.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/interrogacao.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="anjos" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Anjos da Natureza</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="acessoria.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/caneta.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="acessoria" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Acessoria Ambiental</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="projetos.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/papel.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="projetos" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Projetos</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="doacao.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/presente.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="doacao" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Doação</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="contato.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/telefone.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="contato" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Contato</div>
    </div></a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="mais.html"><div id="content-box1">
    <img src="data/mais.gif" height="32" width="32"
    id="mais" style="float:right;"> <div style="">Mais</div>
    </div></a>

  </div>
```

Added this `CSS`:

```
.menu { width: 30%; float: left; }
```

Comment: If you also add `width: 100%;` to the `#content-box1` your menu items will take up the available space.

Comment: True. But there is a lot of bloating in the code that has to be different than his, but hey, that's not the question. Don't want to start on that :)

Comment: Can't agree more! :) @user3306761 You might want to look at [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).